# Define a function that jumps outside paired delimiters (including braces, parens and quotes)?

Tags: elisp, regular-expressions

I have this Vim command to jump outside any parentheses or quotes or double quotes or bracked, when you're inside a closed region. When I press jj fast, it allows me to jump outside the closed region:

```
inoremap jj <Esc>/[)}"'\]>]<CR>:nohl<CR>a
```

Note that the regular expression begins after `<Esc>`. I was missing this in Emacs.

I decided to give a try with the following:

```el
(key-chord-define evil-insert-state-map "jj" 
  ;; Escape from capsuled string
  '(lambda () 
     (interactive) 
     (forward-char 1)
     (insert " ")))
```

For example, * is the place of the cursor.

```
This is an another "example of a string *" within this sentence
```

Pressing the `jj` fast allows me to jump outside the string inside the sentence.

**2 questions:**

**1.** It's only working if the cursor is on the last character before the quote. And not in middle for example. How to solve it?

**2.** How get it working for single quotes ('), brackets '}', or parentheses ())?.

Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Comment: You probably want to mention the mode of the buffer, e.g., what kind of text or programming language this is for. Each mode defines what constitute paired delimiters, for example.

Comment: if you use `smartparens` or `paredit` you can use the commands `sp-up-sexp`/`paredit-forward-up` (bound to `C-M-n`) to do this. It should work in any major mode as long as sp/paredit is active.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a function I use:

```lisp
(defun my-step-out-forward ()
  "Step forward out of current list or string."
  (interactive)
  (if (nth 3 (syntax-ppss (point)))
      (progn
        (forward-char)
        (while (and (not (eobp)) (nth 3 (syntax-ppss (point))))
          (forward-char)))
    (up-list)))
```

The `syntax-ppss` stuff is a bit obtuse, but what it does is get a set of info about your current position in the buffer, the 3rd piece being if you are inside a string.  So if you are, it walks forward until it's out of the string.  There may be a better way to do this, but for an interactive function I find it's good enough.  The `up-list` is the easier part, it simply jumps outside the nearest enclosing paren, for whatever is defined to be a paren in the current mode.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It was the right one, it works fine with quotes, single quotes and brackets/parentheses. Thanks for that, I appreciate it! –

Answer (score 3):

```lisp
(defun ar-leave-delimited-forward ()
  "Go one char beyond string, paren, bracket etc. "
  (interactive)
  (ar-beginn-of-delimited)
  (forward-sexp))

(defun ar-beginn-of-delimited ()
  "Go to beginn of a string or parentized/braced/bracketed. "
  (let ((pps (parse-partial-sexp (point-min) (point))))
    (cond
     ((nth 3 pps)
      (goto-char (nth 8 pps)))
     ((nth 1 pps)
      (goto-char (nth 1 pps))))))
```

Code is developed here:

https://github.com/emacs-berlin/leave-delimited/blob/master/leave-delimited.el

which provides also an `ar-leave-delimited-backward`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I wish I could validate it as the right one but scottfrazer above was earlier with it and his function is also shorter. I upvoted it anyway, it works fine with quotes, single quotes and brackets/parentheses. Thanks for that, I appreciate it!

Comment: Neat, I hadn't thought about going to the beginning then jumping of the sexp.

Answer (score 0):

I previously posted this as a comment, but I think this tip is useful enough to warrant an answer.

As we know, in Lisp, code is organized into nested lists, or trees, of s-expressions. To jump "outside a delimiter" is then analogous to moving "up" the list/tree.

If you use [`smartparens`](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens) or [`paredit`](https://github.com/odyssomay/paredit) you can use the commands `sp-up-sexp`/`paredit-forward-up` (bound to `C-M-n`) to move up the tree. It should work in any major mode as long as `smartparens` or `paredit` is active.

Consider the following tree of sexps, where the cursor is a pipe:

```lisp
(define (greet-someone name) 
  (apply string-append `("Hello, |" ,name "!\n")))
```

Repeatedly pressing `C-M-n` take you outside the quotes, then outside the quasiquote, then outside the `(apply ...)` expression, then outside the entire `define`. Pressing `C-M-p` (`sp`/`paredit-backward-down`) will do the same thing in reverse.

Along with these "up" commands, there are also commands to go in the opposite directions:

`C-M-d`: `down-list`/`sp-down-sexp`/`paredit-forward-down` `C-M-u`: `up-list`/`sp-backward-up-sexp`/`paredit-backward-up`

These commands are extremely useful for navigating (especially in Lisp), but I don't see them mentioned a lot, at least relative to their value.

(There are also built-in commands `forward-list` and `backward-list` but they don't work in as many cases and the `smartparens`/`paredit` ones do.)